# Test for not all spaces

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, spaces

How do you say it in a condition that `name is not equal to spaces`? I have this

```
name != null && name !== ' '
```

But it still continues to search with multiple spaces. It only stops searching with one space. How about if there are a lot of space?

Comment: This is not "searching", it is "testing". It also has nothing whatsoever to do with Angular.

Comment: When you say "spaces" do you mean literally only the _space_ character, or do you mean any kind of whitespace including newlines or tabs? In other words, would you consider the string `" \t\n"` to contain "only spaces" (whitespace) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `trim` function. It'll remove all white space and therefore match.

`name !== null && name.trim() !== ''`

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned to torazburo, OP said "spaces", not "whitespace", so `trim()` would not work if that is really what was meant. I never like to assume these things one way or the other, so I put a comment on the question asking for clarification.

Comment: I made the assumption that it's spaces since the variable is name and I'd bet she's using an input instead of a text area

Comment: Actually you assumed "whitespace", not "spaces" as the OP asked about. Consider `" \t\n".trim()` - it returns an empty string even though the original string contains _whitespace_ characters that are not _spaces_. It is fairly likely that "whitespace" was the intent (including `"\t"` and `"\n"` as well as `" "`, but it is best to find out which was really meant.

Comment: I agree, curious to see what Char is looking for exactly. Although, I can't imagine you'd want someone's name to contain ```\t``` or ```\n```

Answer (score 0):

Test for the presence of any non whitespace character:

```
/\S/.test(string)
```

```js
function notAllSpaces(str) { return str && /\S/.test(str); }

const data= ['', ' ', '  ', ' A '];

data.forEach(str => console.log("'" + str + "'", 
  notAllSpaces(str) ? "not all spaces" : "all spaces"));
```

To test for the presence of **any** character which is not a space, including whitespace characters like tab and newline, replace the `\S` with `[^ ]`.

Comment: OP didn't specify "whitespace", just "spaces", so `\S` would not be quite the right thing if that is taken literally. (Of course `[^ ]` would work in this case.) I put a comment on the question asking for clarification on this.